# SQLite3 Database - No such collation sequence error

Tags: sqlite, collation

I am getting `no such collation sequence: en_US` error when I try to do a `select count(*)` from OR insert a record into a particular table in the database.

I am no database expert but I tried to google the error and what I understand is that the table is created with `COLLATION SEQUENCE` function set to `en_US` which the SQLite is not familiar with.

Is there any solution to this error (without dropping the table and creating a new one).

Comment: Can you edit your question, and paste the output of `.schema your_table_name`.

Comment: I'm having similar issue when trying to do `vacuum`. Although I can't drop those indexes. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you CatCall. I tried a .schema tablename and I saw that the collation sequence was set on 2 of the indexes. I dropped them and recreated without the collation sequence and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Ran into the same thing, although we did not recreate our index.  It turned out to be one we didn't need.